# what can be the reason for no permission even using root or sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

When `root` or using `sudo`, I cannot write to some files.

I have a file *fileA* with permissions 750

```
fileA rwxr_x___ root root
```

When I run a program as `root` or using `sudo`, the system prompt is:

```
no write permission to this file.
```

What can be the possible reason?

Comment: What program are you trying to run on the file? Can you append to the file? `echo EXTRA >> fileA`

Comment: The file is on a CDROM, or a file system which has been marked read-only due to errors?

Comment: We need more information.  The group permission clearly indicates write permissions isn't allowed.

Comment: @Ramhound: The group is `root`, but so is the owner. The owner has write attributes, so it should be working.

Comment: I was just pointing out something that was odd.  Is linux persmisions not normally "owner-group-everyone'else"?

Answer (score 2):

Run `lsattr` and make sure the files don't have the `i` attribute set. That means "immutable", and when it is set, nobody - not even root - can change them.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the files are not located on a read only device, or that the device is mounted as read only.